# WebGL - When to call gl.Flush?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I just noticed today that this method, Flush() is available.
Not able to find detailed documentation on it.

What exactly does this do?
Is this required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming it's semantically equivalent to the classic GL `glFlush` then no, it will almost never be required. OpenGL is an asynchronous API — you queue up work to be done and it is done when it can be. `glFlush` is still asynchronous but forces any accumulated buffers to be emptied as quickly as they can be, however long that may take; it basically says to the driver "if you were planning to hold anything back for any reason, please don't".

It's usually done only for a platform-specific reason related to the coupling of OpenGL and the other display mechanisms on that system. For example, one platform might need all GL work to be ordered not to queue before the container that it will be drawn into can be moved to the screen. Another might allow piping of resources from a background thread into the main OpenGL context but not guarantee that they're necessarily available for subsequent calls until you've flushed (e.g. if multithreading ends up creating two separate queues where there might otherwise be one then flush might insert a synchronisation barrier across both).

Any platform with a double buffer or with back buffering as per the WebGL model will automatically ensure that buffers proceed in a timely manner. Queueing is to aid performance but should have no negative observable consequences. So you don't have to do anything manually.

If you decline to flush and don't strictly need to even when you semantically perhaps should, but your graphics are predicated on real-time display anyway, then you're probably going to be suffering at worst a fraction of a second of latency.

Comment: `glFlush()` does not block until the work is done. It only guarantees that the work will be executed in a finite amount of time. What you're describing is the behavior of `glFinish()`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi you're absolutely correct, and I'm forced to ask significant questions about my memory. I'll edit the answer on the assumption that it'll cause the tick to vanish; if that fails then I'll kill this answer and write a separate one as — as you are implicitly aware — this is not the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Alright, I think I lost the 'correct answer' points on account of having edited, as if anyone cares about that, so hopefully my updated answer is [closer to] correct. It's the same timbre of thing, being asynchronicity and ordering specific activity with scheduling, so all the obiter stuff could more or less stay but obviously a different specific behaviour is being requested.

Comment: No worries about the points. I just wanted to make sure that we don't end up with incorrect information in a top voted and accepted answer. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: With a further negative vote, I'm marking this as community wiki, as it's obvious that community input would be valuable.

Answer (score 16):

`gl.flush` in WebGL does have it's uses but it's driver and browser specific.

For example, because Chrome's GPU architecture is multi-process you can do this

```
function var loadShader = function(gl, shaderSource, shaderType) {
  var shader = gl.createShader(shaderType);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  return shader;
}

var vs = loadShader(gl, someVertexShaderSource, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
var fs = loadShader(gl, someFragmentShaderSource, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
var p = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(p, vs);
gl.attachShader(p, fs);
gl.linkProgram(p);
```

At this point all of the commands might be sitting in the command
queue with nothing executing them yet. So, issue a flush

```
gl.flush();
```

Now, because we know that compiling and linking programs is slow depending on how large and complex they are so we can wait a while before trying using them and do other stuff

```
setTimeout(continueLater, 1000);  // continue 1 second later
```

now do other things like setup the page or UI or something

1 second later `continueLater` will get called. It's likely our shaders finished compiling and linking.

```
function continueLater() {

  // check results, get locations, etc.
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ||
      !gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ||
      !gl.getProgramParameter(p, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
     alert("shaders didn't compile or program didn't link");
     ...etc... 
   }

   var someLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_someUniform");
   ...etc...
}
```

I believe Google Maps uses this technique as they have to compile many very complex shaders and they'd like the page to stay responsive. If they called `gl.compileShader` or `gl.linkProgram` and immediately called one of the query functions like `gl.getShaderParameter` or `gl.getProgramParameter` or `gl.getUniformLocation` the program would freeze while the shader is first validated and then sent to the driver to be compiled. By not doing the querying immediately but waiting a moment they can avoid that pause in the UX.

Unfortunately this only works for Chrome AFAIK because other browsers are not multi-process and I believe all drivers compile/link synchronously.

There maybe be other reasons to call `gl.flush` but again it's very driver/os/browser specific. As an example let's say you were going to draw 1000 objects and to do that took 5000 webgl calls. It likely would require more than that but just to have a number lets pick 5000. 4 calls to `gl.uniformXXX` and 1 calls to `gl.drawXXX` per object.

It's possible all 5000 of those calls fit in the browser's (Chrome) or driver's command buffer. Without a flush they won't start executing until the the browser issues a `gl.flush` for you (which it does so it can composite your results on the screen). That means the GPU might be sitting idle while you issue 1000, then 2000, then 3000, etc.. commands since they're just sitting in a buffer. `gl.flush` tells the system "Hey, those commands I added, please make sure to start executing them". So you might decide to call `gl.flush` after each 1000 commands.

The problem though is `gl.flush` is not free otherwise you'd call it after every command to make sure it executes as soon as possible. On top of that each driver/browser works in different ways. On some drivers calling `gl.flush` every few 100 or 1000 WebGL calls might be a win. On others it might be a waste of time.

Sorry, that was probably too much info :p

Comment: more info here is appreciated, i didn't understand the accepted answer